# The record memory allocation button is gone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to record memory allocation in an Android Studio 3.0.1 using an Android Profile. But I am wondering why a "record memory allocation" button is gone for some devices.

Device Lg Nexus 5 - the record button exists.

Device Samsung s3 - the record button is gone.

What can be the reason and how to return the button?

Is there any option in the device settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the USB usage mode(from Charging to Transfer files). In my case, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> This button appears only when connected to a device running Android 7.1 or lower.

You can find more info here: [Developer android - memory profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler). Check 'Memory Profiler overview' section.

Comment: You may want to add link to the relevant part of the documentation you quoted.